# MongoDB | Query an array of objects based on multiple properties

Tags: mongodb

If this is my data:

```js
{
  owner: 'John',
  pets:[
    {
      name: 'Oscar',
      age: 7,
      type: 'dog'
    },{
      name: 'Oscar II',
      age: 3,
      type: 'dog'
    }
  ]
},{
  owner: 'Sally',
  pets:[
    {
      name: 'Spot',
      age: 7,
      type: 'cat'
    },{
      name: 'Mister Dog',
      age: 3,
      type: 'dog'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I build a query to get every owner that has a dog that is 7.

I tried:

```js
Owners.findOne({
  'pets.age': 7,
  'pets.type': 'dog'
});
```

But this returns every owner who has a pet with an age of 7 OR with a type of dog. In the case of the data above it return both Sally & John. How can I just get John?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **$elemMatch** to specify all constraints to the same element:

```
Owners.findOne({
  'pets': {
      '$elemMatch' : {
          'age': 7,
          'type': 'dog'
       }
   }
});
```